# Code coverage tool visual studio 2010 c++

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

does any know how to do some unit testing in c++ with the code coverage results working in visual studio 2010, I have looked for some answers everywhere. I want to keep the project I am testing and the testing project separate. Using a project the outputs a static lib is not a solution as the code coverage tool in VS 2010 can't put instrumentation code inside of the lib. Ive tried dll as the project to be tested, but then that cant link properly with test created due to the CLR:safe parameter being turned on for tests. Any ideas people? Or are MS just incapable of making a c++ code coverage tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Full disclosure: I'm on the team that maintains this feature)

Native C++ code coverage is supported by VS2010, but as you've seen, you can only instrument linked binaries (e.g. .dll or .exe).  This means that the code you want to collect coverage for must be linked into a binary image before you instrument it.

What unit test framework are you using?  It sounds like your test project is pure managed C++ (`/clr:safe`).  If you build your native C++ project as a DLL, your test project should at least be able to call into the native DLL using [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28VS.71%29.aspx) calls.  By doing this, you don't actually need to link your native .lib into your test project.

Comment: Currently we are using the Microsoft Unit Testing Framework: (Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting) which is by default in /clr:safe. Im still unsure how to link the test file to my dll, in the next post I will show you my testfile. PM me your email, and I'll send the project I'm playing around with (very basic program and its very small), and you can see for yourself it doesn't work.

Comment: "Native C++ code coverage is supported by VS2010" <-- what What WHAT?

Comment: @user531571: StackOverflow encourages people to keep things public so we can all learn from one another.  Can you edit your question and post the code?  I'd be happy to modify my answer and help further.

Comment: @Billy: yeah, it does, but sadly it's not very well exposed since there is no real built-in test framework for native code which really goes hand-in-hand with code coverage.  If you're feeling adventurous, though, you can collect native code coverage by hand using command-line tools.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phuene/archive/2007/05/03/code-coverage-instrumentation.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phuene/archive/2007/05/14/code-coverage-collection.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
//MyTestfile


#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MathFuncsDll.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;

using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting;

namespace anothertest
{
    [TestClass]
    public ref class cuttwotest
    {
    public: 
        [TestMethod]
        void TestMethod1()
        {
            Assert::AreEqual ((MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Add(2,3)), 6, 0.05);
        }
    };
}
```